# Powershell Count lines in file

Tags: string, file, powershell

### Issue

`Measure-Object -Line` behaviour is not consistent and does not return the correct number of lines when trying to read a file.

Using `.Count` seems to fix this specific issue but once again it is not consistent because it does not work the same way when working with a string.

### Question

How can I consistently get the correct number of lines from a text or file?

### MWE

```
$File       = ".\test.ini"
$FileContent  = Get-Content $File
$Content =
"    # 1
    [2]
    3

    5

    [7]

    ; 9
"

$EndOfFile    = $FileContent | Measure-Object -Line
$EndOfText    = $Content | Measure-Object -Line

Write-Output "Lines from file: $($EndOfFile.Lines)"
Write-Output "Lines from text: $($EndOfText.Lines)"
Write-Output "Count from file: $($FileContent.Count)"
Write-Output "Count from text: $($Content.Count)"
```

**Note:** The content of `test.ini` are the exact same of the `$Content` variable.

### Output

```
Lines from file: 6
Lines from text: 9
Count from file: 9
Count from text: 1
```

Comment: When you define a string, it's a single object.  `Get-Content` returns *an array of strings* by default unless you pass the `-Raw` switch.  This behavior is entirely consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It true what's @TheIncorrigible1 is saying. To do it consistent in your example, you have to do it this way:

```
$File       = ".\test.ini"
$FileContent  = Get-Content $File

$Content = @(
    "# 1",
    "[2]",
    "3",
    "",
    "5",
    ""
    "[7]",
    ""
    "; 9"
)

$EndOfFile    = $FileContent | Measure-Object -Line
$EndOfText    = $Content | Measure-Object -Line

Write-Output "Lines from file: $($EndOfFile.Lines)"
Write-Output "Lines from text: $($EndOfText.Lines)"
Write-Output "Count from file: $($FileContent.Count)"
Write-Output "Count from text: $($Content.Count)"
```

Consistent output:

```
Lines from file: 6
Lines from text: 6
Count from file: 9
Count from text: 9
```

Comment: Can you highlight the difference? (sorry, I don't notice any...)

Comment: @Starnutoditopo the difference is when setting the **$Content** variable using **@( )**, this will initiate an array object, which will make the desired 'output' consistent.